# Exporting pandas data frame to google sheets with df2gspread returns Error: Setting a MultiIndex dtype to anything other than object is not supported

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, df2gspread

I'm trying to upload a df to google sheets using the df2gspread module.
The data frames looks like this:

| Org Name | TSTAcme |  |  | TSTExample |  |  | Total |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Cost | Net Revenue | Revenue | Cost | Net Revenue | Revenue | Cost | Net Revenue | Revenue |
| Date |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-01-03 | 6.49 | 26039.51 | 26046.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6.49 | 26039.51 | 26046.00 |
| 2023-01-06 | 3.54 | 36778.46 | 36782.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3.54 | 36778.46 | 36782.00 |
| 2023-01-09 | 4.13 | 29825.87 | 29830.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4.13 | 29825.87 | 29830.00 |
| 2023-01-10 | 0.59 | 20094.41 | 20095.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.59 | 20094.41 | 20095.00 |
| 2023-01-11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1.12 | 38581.88 | 38583.00 | 1.12 | 38581.88 | 38583.00 |
| 2023-01-12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1.18 | 36127.82 | 36129.00 | 1.18 | 36127.82 | 36129.00 |
| 2023-01-17 | 0.00 | 28908.00 | 28908.00 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.00 | 28908.00 | 28908.00 |
| Total | 14.75 | 141646.25 | 141661.00 | 2.30 | 74709.70 | 74712.00 | 17.05 | 216355.95 | 216373.00 |

The pandas to_excel function works fine and I'm able to export this to an excel file without any problems.

```
Setting a MultiIndex dtype to anything other than object is not supported
```

The above error comes up when I try to upload this to a google sheet using d2g.upload function.

I have tried exporting this to excel and then upload the data frame after reading it from the excel file but it's of no use.

I have also tried converting the multi index to object but no success.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(
             pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)
             .reset_index().astype(object)
           )
```

I have tried other solutions from other threads but haven't been able to resolve this error.

Comment: About `The above error comes up when I try to upload this to a google sheet using d2g.upload function.`, can you provide the script for correctly replicating it?

Comment: @Tanaike here is the script to replicate the issue: [link](https://easyupload.io/dffeow)